# Is there a matplotlib function to plot both x and y axis in parallel?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there any way to make a similar plot as below using matplotlib? I haven't found anything similar on the web. Basically, I need to plot 'Time hr' on the y-axis and 'Elapsed hr' on the x-axis, but I don't need any plot, just the values appearing as in the plot example. 'Elapsed hr' might look like a secondary axis but it is not. I don't know what plot type to use in matplotlib to accomplish this and not sure if this is even possible. Perhaps, this can be done using other libraries? I appreciate any help and advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled. You need a plot without plotting anything? Of course, you could just display two axes on a plot. As we cannot rotate an x-axis, we create a [twin axis object](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html?highlight=twinx#matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx) and use the second y-axis.

```
#sample data generation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
n = 50
start = pd.to_datetime("2021-01-01")
date_range = pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 500, n), unit="D") + start
cat1 = "Date"
cat2 = "Elapsed"
df = pd.DataFrame({cat1: date_range, cat2: np.random.randint(10, 30, n), })

#the actual plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 8), constrained_layout=True)

#left axis
ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax1.spines[["right", "bottom", "top"]].set_visible(False)
ax1.set_ylim(df[cat1].min(), df[cat1].max())
bbox_dic = dict(edgecolor="lightgrey", facecolor="white", boxstyle="round")
ax1.annotate(cat1, xy=(0, 1.02), xycoords="axes fraction", fontsize="large", ha="center", bbox=bbox_dic) 

#right axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
spine_distance = 0.7
ax2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", spine_distance)) 
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", direction="in", pad=-30)
ax2.spines[["left", "bottom", "top"]].set_visible(False)
ax2.set_ylim(df[cat2].min(), df[cat2].max())
ax2.annotate(cat2, xy=(spine_distance, 1.02), xycoords="axes fraction", fontsize="large", ha="center", bbox=bbox_dic) 

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Should the two axis scales be related to each other (e.g., one is the date time, the other the time elapsed from the start value of the primary axis), you could simplify the procedure and just use the opposite y-axis as the secondary axis with a recalculated scale as shown in [this matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html):

```
#sample data generation
import pandas as pd
date_range = pd.date_range("20210321", periods=150, freq="18min")
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": date_range })


#the actual plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, date2num

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 8))

start_time = df["Date"].min()

#left axis
ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax1.spines[["bottom", "top"]].set_visible(False)
ax1.set_ylim(df["Date"].min(), df["Date"].max())
bbox_dic = dict(edgecolor="lightgrey", facecolor="white", boxstyle="round")
ax1.annotate("Date", xy=(0, 1.02), xycoords="axes fraction", fontsize="large", ha="right", bbox=bbox_dic) 
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%m-%d %H:%M"))

def date2elapse(x):
    return (x-date2num(start_time))*24

def elapse2date(x):
    return x/24+date2num(start_time)

#right axis
ax2 = ax1.secondary_yaxis("right", functions=(date2elapse, elapse2date))
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", direction="in", pad=-25)
ax1.annotate("Elapsed (in h)", xy=(1, 1.02), xycoords="axes fraction", fontsize="large", ha="center", bbox=bbox_dic) 

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.4, bottom=0.1, right=0.7, top=0.9)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Mr. T - thanks for your answer. Maybe I wasn't very clear about what I actually needed, since I am new to programming and I wasn't able to explain properly. Basically, I have a dataframe with multiple columns. One of the columns is Datetime, and the other one is Elapsedtime. I understand elapsedtime is a derivative of Datetime, but let's consider it is just given. So I want to plot on my yaxis - Datetime, and my xaxis - Elapsedtime, however instead of a line, I want to show the values of xaxis just like you have done above. Hope I am clear.

Comment: You create the axis object (as shown above) with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, then you can set the axis limits with `ax.set_ylim(yminvalue, ymaxvalue)` and `ax.set_xlim(xminvalue, xmaxvalue)`. No plotting of data points involved,  if that is what you mean. Difficult to know.

Comment: Thanks. I want to make a subplot with multiple subplots (ax1, ax2, ax3 ... ).Please see img: https://github.com/serdar-bayramov/image/blob/main/images/img.JPG. I am trying to use the code you suggested, then the other subplots don't get plotted. Can you please show me how I can use this alongside other subplots? On the image, you will see that Elapsedtime is plotted as a line, but I want it only as values of elapsedtime in yaxis (the same way you showed), while the rest of the line plots should remain.

Comment: This question is constantly changing the topic. Why didn't you ask this question in the first place, and how would I know how you created this image? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then ask a new question.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I thought it was irrelevant to mention there are other subplots since I thought if I could get this Datetime vs elapsedtime plot right, then it would be just a matter to include the other axis. Also, I didn't include the code snippet because it is quite long. Thanks for the links, I will read them and will try to formulate my question more precisely. Cheers.